# Xbox 360 2 Players, one live account and one console how can they both join an online game?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console, xbox-network

My Sons want to play with friends on an online Minecraft game together. We only have one live account though, what can we do to be able to all join in online? Can 2 live accounts play the same online game from one console? Is there a way to play online without another live account being purchased? Please can someone help us, thanks.

Comment: Do any of their XBOX Live accounts have a Gold Membership?

Answer (score 3):

If one account has access to XBox LIVE Gold, you can simply have the other log into the "Guest" account that is on the XBox console.

Answer (score 0):

When you join, make sure both controllers are on. The live account should select join, then it will ask to sign in. The other controller signs into the one labeled "Guest" and the live controller pushes A to start joining.

Please note that Guests' items **DO NOT** save. You will have to put the inventory into a chest before leaving.